# Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Tags: ocaml

I was wondering why I have this error.

```
let put_list v i list=
    if i < 0 then invalid_arg "index must be a positive"
    else
    let rec put_list_rec v i list = match list with
         [] -> []
       | e::t -> if i = 1 then v::t
                 else e::put_list_rec v (i-1) t
    in put_list_rec v i list;;
```

And this is the error that I get.

```
put_list 'x' 3 [’-’; ’-’; ’-’; ’-’; ’-’; ’-’];;
```

```
Line 1, characters 14-15:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 18-19:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 23-24:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 27-28:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 32-33:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 36-37:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 41-42:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 45-46:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 50-51:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 54-55:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 59-60:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Line 1, characters 63-64:
Alert deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers

Error: Line 1, characters 15-16:
Error: Illegal character (\128)
```

Comment: `’` (U+2019, RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) is not the character you want. Try `'` (U+0027, APOSTROPHE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, you're inserting `’` (U+2019, RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) rather than a plain `'`.

Likely cause is not using a plain text editor to write code. Ensure that your text editor is set to "plain text."